# Module for putting blocks in menus

Tags: 6, blocks

Is there any module that allows me to put a block in a menu?
I wanted to add some related content, or a big image about the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try the [OM Maximenu](http://drupal.org/project/om_maximenu) module.

> "Maximize your main navigation by adding text, images, videos,
>   slideshow, tabs, menu blocks, user info ..."
>
> That is now possible by using OM Maximenu which can create menus with
>   all other module blocks you want as attachments, modules like views,
>   slideshow, menu, user, nice menus, quicktabs, and custom blocks with
>   tables, lists, images, videos, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Sure; these are called 'megamenus' or 'meganavs' and there is a module directly for this: the [Megamenu](http://drupal.org/project/megamenu) module.

> Mega menus are a type of drop-down, which seeks to overcome some of the usability drawbacks to traditional style drop-downs. Primarily, mega menus have two advantages:
>
> 1. The information architecture of your navigation is made clearer and is visible all at once
> 2. The amount of clicking, searching, and navigating is reduced
>
> This module allows you to build mega menus by leveraging jQuery and the existing Drupal menu system. Megamenu takes a Drupal menu that is 3 levels deep, and converts it into a categorized 3-level mega menu, which is placed into your site as a block.

The 7.2-x branch allows "embeded blocks within mega menus"

Comment: Is there any module in Drupal 6 ?

Comment: I found out this module http://drupal.org/project/nodeblock that is being used in whitehouse.gov site, but am not able to figure out how s it tied up with menus, i cannot use mega menu as emebded menus are supported only for 7 i think

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to try out [menu attach block](https://drupal.org/project/menu_attach_block). As advertised, it attaches a block to a menu item:

> Menu Attach Block allows you to attach blocks to standard core Drupal
>   menu items. This is especially useful for creating complex dropdown
>   menus and mega menus.

[image]